# Wont add value to expression

Tags: powershell, startswith

I am trying to popluate the $targetdb with a string value using the .startswith but it wont fill in. I have also tried using the the -match operator and still no luck. I just need to the $targetdb filled by the users first character of the lastname. Any help would be great thank you.

```
$lastname = "$($_.Surname)"

$region = Read-Host 'Region? (CR, XR, SR, CHI)'
If ($region -match "CR") {$office = "CR*"} 
ElseIf ($region -match "SR") {$office = "SR*"}
ElseIf ($region -match "XR") {$office = "CR XR"}
ElseIf ($region -match "CHI") {$office = "NR*"}
Else {Write-Error 'Enter Correct Parameter!'}
$depart = Read-Host 'Department Name?'
If ($lastname.StartsWith("R-Z")) {$TargetDB = "$crmbxdb3"}
$filter = "department -like ""$depart"" -and Enabled -eq ""True"" -and office -like ""$office"""
$output = Get-ADUser -Filter $filter | Format-Table @{label="EmailAddress";expression={$_.UserPrincipalName}}, @{label="LastName";expression={$_.Surname}}, @{label="TargetDatabase";expression={$TargetDB}} | Out-String
$output
```

Comment: When assigning $lastname, change your syntax to either: $lastname = $_.Surname or $lastname = "$($_.Surname)". The current syntax expands $_ before accessing the Surname property. You also don't have to surround $lastname with quotes in your If statement.

Comment: That didn't work, same result. I never get any errors so its been difficult to debug.

Answer (score 2):

`"$lastname".StartsWith("R-Z")` is probably not doing what you expect - it tests whether the string starts literally with the three characters "R","-" and "Z".

If you want to test for a range of characters, use `-match`:

```
if($lastname -match "^[r-z]") { $TargetDB = "$crmbxdb3" }
```

Comment: if($lastname -match "^[r-z]") { $TargetDB = "$crmbxdb3" } gives me that same result, nothing.

Comment: Have you verified that the value of `$lastname` is indeed what you expect it to be?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
If ("$lastname".StartsWith("R")) {$TargetDB = "$crmbxdb3"}
```

instead of

```
If ("$lastname".StartsWith("R")) {$TargetDB = "$crmbxdb3"}**
```

it works for me...

try also this: `If ($lastname.StartsWith("R")) {$TargetDB = "$crmbxdb3"}` skipping quotes for $lastname

Comment: I'm assuming the problem is that $TargetDB variable doesn't get filled in with the value of $crmbxdb3 even though $lastname starts with "R-Z" ? Have you tried to add something like Write-Host $TargetDB within the code to see what is the value of the variable during the execution? You can also use PowerGUI Script editor to help you debug the code

Comment: Thank you, yes I am wanting the $targetdb to equal a database based on what letter the $lastname starts with. I have updated my code to what I currently have but I get nothing. the ".StartsWith" seems to not be working, I have also tried -match as well and I get nothing. If I put if $lastname="Ryan" it works just fine.